# Dynamic capture templates in emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode, capture

Does anyone know how to accomplish dynamic capture templates in emacs org-mode?

I've read the `org-capture template` documentation and searched for "Dynamic org-capture templates" but cannot seem to find out how to accomplish the following:

```
C-c c                       (to show capture templates)
"a"                         (select example "activity" template)
Activity: math              (<--need completion here if possible)
Topic: multiplication       (<--need completion here if possible)
Date: 2017-09-11            (<--need default to todays date)
Start time: 07:00 AM        (<--need to define AM/PM easily)
Duration: 20                (<--duration in mins or hours if possible)
Unit: mins                  (<--necessary?)
```

Whereas if another `Activity` was chosen (yoga), "Topic" changes to "Type" and adds "Class" or the like:

```
C-c c
"a"
Activity: physical education
Type: yoga
Class: Level 2 flow
Date: 2017-09-11
Start time: 07:00 AM
Duration: 90
Unit: mins
```

Where in an `org-capture-template` can I specify the `Activity` to `Option` mapping?

Also, is it possible to use completion to make capturing the data quicker?

Comment: You might want to use  Yasnippet  templates.

Comment: I've been playing with `yasnippet` and `yankpad`, but can't find a way to setup dynamic templates with them either. Any ideas?